# Algorithm for finding the maximum number of non-overlapping lines on the x axis

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm not exactly sure how to ask this, but I'll try to be as specific as possible.
Imagine a tetris screen with only rectangles, of different shapes, falling to the bottom.
I want to compute the maximum number of rectangles that I can fit one next to the other without any overlapping ones. I've named them lines in the title because I'm actually only interested in the length of the rectangle when computing, or the line parallel to the x axis that it's falling towards.

So basically I have a custom type with a start and end, both integers between 0 and 100. Say we have a list of these rectangles ranging from 1 to n. rectangle_n.start (unless it's the rectangle closest to the origin) has to be > rectangle_(n-1).end so that they will never overlap. 
I'm reading the rectangle coordinates (both are x axis coordinates) from a file with random numbers.

As an example:
consider this list of rectangle type objects

```
rectangle_list {start, end} = {{1,2}, {3,5}, {4,7} {9,12}}
```

We can observe that the 3rd object has its start coordinate 4 < the previous rectangle's end coordinate which is 5. So in sorting this list, I would have to remove the 2nd or the 3rd object so that they don't overlap.

I'm not sure if there is a type for this kind of problem so I didn't know how else to name it. I'm interested in an algorithm that can be applied on a list of such objects and would sort them out accordingly.

I've tagged this with c++ because the code I'm writing is c++ but any language would do for the algorithm.
[image: initial state]

[image: final state]

Comment: I think you'll need a heuristic for this one. Why not start with the smallest segments first?

Comment: To be clear, it doesn't matter if you remove the 2nd or 3rd rectangle because it is the number of rectangles you want to maximise, not the sum of the total length?

Comment: Do you actually mean: "We can observe that the 3rd object has its start coordinate 4 < the previous rectangle's end coordinate which is **5**."?

Comment: @Tom yes, that's about it. The problem is, I need to decide which one to remove based on multiple things like: is either of them impairing the placement of what other rectangles ? which one is longer ? etc

Comment: Also, are you free to move the rectangles back and forth as they fall, or not?

Comment: @John They don't actually fall. I'm just interested in the landing coordinates on the x axis. The start and end coordinates for each, which are read from a file are fixed, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are essentially solving the following problem. Suppose we have `n` intervals `{[x_1,y_1),[x_2,y_2),...,[x_n,y_n)}` with `x_1<=x_2<=...<=x_n`. We want to find a maximal subset of these intervals such that there are no overlaps between any intervals in the subset.

The naive solution is dynamic programming. It guarantees to find the best solution. Let `f(i)`, `0<=i<=n`, be the size of the maximal subset up to interval `[x_i,y_i)`. We have equation (this is latex):

```
f(i)=\max_{0<=j<i}{f(j)+d(i,j)}
```

where `d(i,j)=1` if and only if `[x_i,y_i)` and `[x_j,y_j)` have no overlaps; otherwise `d(i,j)` takes zero. You can iteratively compute `f(i)`, starting from `f(0)=0`. `f(n)` gives the size of the maximal subset. To get the actual subset, you need to keep a separate array `s(i)=\argmax_{0<=j<i}{f(j)+d(i,j)}`. You then need to backtrack to get the 'path'.

This is an `O(n^2)` algorithm: you need to compute each `f(i)` and for each `f(i)` you need `i` number of tests. I think there should be a `O(nlogn)` algorithm, but I am not so sure.

EDIT: an implementation in Lua:

```lua
function find_max(list)
    local ret, f, b = {}, {}, {}
    f[0], b[0] = 0, 0
    table.sort(list, function(a,b) return a[1]<b[1] end)
    -- dynamic programming
    for i, x in ipairs(list) do 
        local max, max_j = 0, -1
        x = list[i]
        for j = 0, i - 1 do
            local e = j > 0 and list[j][2] or 0
            local score = e <= x[1] and 1 or 0
            if f[j] + score > max then
                max, max_j = f[j] + score, j
            end
        end
        f[i], b[i] = max, max_j
    end
    -- backtrack
    local max, max_i = 0, -1
    for i = 1, #list do
        if f[i] > max then -- don't use >= here
            max, max_i = f[i], i
        end
    end
    local i, ret = max_i, {}
    while true do
        table.insert(ret, list[i])
        i = b[i]
        if i == 0 then break end
    end
    return ret
end

local l = find_max({{1,2}, {4,7}, {3,5}, {8,11}, {9,12}})
for _, x in ipairs(l) do
    print(x[1], x[2])
end
```

Comment: Great solution. What makes you think there might be a `O(n log n)` algorithm?

Comment: In computational biology, there is a related by more complex problem called alignment chaining, which is known to have a couple of `O(nlogn)` solutions if the objective function is simple enough. If I am right, I can use those algorithms to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I've chosed this as the accepted answer, because it was the most explicit, not only about the solution but also about the requirement. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The name of this problem is bin packing, it is usually considered as a hard problem but can be computed reasonably well for small number of bins.

Here is [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiMFyTWqLhc) explaining common approaches to this problem

EDIT : By hard problem, I mean that some kind of brute force has to be employed. You will have to evaluate a lot of solutions and reject most of them, so usually you need some kind of evaluation mechanism. You need to be able to compare solution, such as "This solution packs 4 rectangles with area of 15" is better than "This solution packs 3 rectangles with area of 16".

Comment: Wrong, it isn't bin packing, which is NP complete, and not a stock-cutting problem either.   There's an O(n²) method if user172818's answer is correct.  Note, in [bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), items don't have fixed locations in the bin.  -1

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a shortcut, so you may have to enumerate the power set in descending order of size and stop on the first match.

The straightforward way to do this is to enumerate combinations of decreasing size. You could do something like this in C++11:

```
template <typename I>
std::set<Span> find_largest_non_overlapping_subset(I start, I finish) {
    std::set<Span> result;
    for (size_t n = std::distance(start, finish); n-- && result.empty();) {
        enumerate_combinations(start, finish, n, [&](I begin, I end) {
            if (!has_overlaps(begin, end)) {
                result.insert(begin, end);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

The implementation of `enumerate_combination` is left as an exercise. I assume you already have `has_overlap`.